# VS 2010 Bookmark All disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my Quick Find window, why is the Bookmark All button disabled?

Comment: Same here, solution anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's disabled if you search for more than just the current document. I am not sure why this restriction is in place however. I would like to bookmark all across the entire solution.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Looks like Bookmark All is enabled for Current Document, Selection, All Open Documents, and Current Block; disabled for Current Project and Entire Solution.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I gave up trying the other options after Solution and Current project but I knew Current Document works. Still hoping for a future workaround or addin to enable this..

Comment: so, the only viable solution seems to execute a "search all", go into Find Results window and cycle through all results pressing F8 like a monkey, then execute a Search > Bookmark all with "Open Documents" option... :)

Answer (score -2):

You can search in Entire Solution with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find and Replace) window.

Comment: That is a workaround, not an answer to the question.